# Can you have more than one root view controller in an Xcode project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to have more than one root view controller in your project. Say you already have a root view controller set on a navigation controller to control its set of scenes.

I would like to set up another one on my other navigation controller so that I can control its scenes better (navigation bar especially!) Can I do this? And if so, how?

Comment: Are you talking about the "root view controller" property of a UINavigationController? Every navigation controller needs one unique root view controller, and you may indeed have multiple navigation controllers in your project - for example if you have a tab bar or a modal navigation controller. It would be helpful if you could describe what exactly you're trying to do, and showed us an example of your view hierarchy.

Comment: Yep, @evOlution, I have a tab bar and therefore have multiple navigation controllers set up to deal with each area (tab). I just checked again, and yes there is a root view controller relationship specified under my outline list for my second navigation controller but this time Xcode won't let me manually add a navigation bar to an associated view whereas it did let me for the first set of scenes. Why is this? I thought it was because there was no root view controller set but I realize now that the table view is the root view that has been embedded in the navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UITabbarcontroller`. Then make every tab a `UINavigationController`. Now u have multiple `NavigationControllers`.

Comment: Yup. I did that. I have a tab bar controller and I have three navigation controllers spinning off of that. What I didn't understand was what root view relationship meant and I didn't know that you can have more than one 'root view' in an app. It was just lack of understanding. Thanks to the help here I understand it much better. It's now just an issue with the navigation bar not being editable directly from storyboard as it was for another set of views previously... (I started looking at root view trying to trouble shoot this)